# Simple regex required

Tags: java, regex

I've never used regexes in my life and by jove it looks like a deep pool to dive into. Anyway,
I need a regex for this pattern (AN is alphanumeric (a-z or 0-9), N is numeric (0-9) and A is alphabetic (a-z)):

```
AN,AN,AN,AN,AN,N,N,N,N,N,N,AN,AN,AN,A,A
```

That's five AN's, followed by six N's, followed by three AN's, followed finally by two A's. 
If it makes a difference, the language I'm using is Java.

Comment: If you are using a specific language, you should tag the question with that language.

Comment: No problem, I'll know for next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[a-z0-9]{5}[0-9]{6}[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}
```

should work in most RE dialects for the tasks as you specified it -- most of them will also support abbreviations such as `\d` (digit) in lieu of `[0-9]` (but if alphabetics need to be lowercase, as you appear to be requesting, you'll probably need to spell out the `a-z` parts).

Comment: I assume you meant [0-9], not [0--9]. Fixed it for you.

Comment: The OP asked for 5 alphanumerics at the start of the pattern, not {6}.. you should probably update this for correctness. Something like this is closer to what the OP asked for: 
[a-z0-9]{5}[0-9]{6}[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}

Answer (score 4):

Replace each AN by [a-z0-9], each N by [0-9], and each A by [a-z].

Comment: This is correct (+1), but the regex is horrible (-1). Alex Martelli's regex is a lot more readable.

Comment: Exactly, he practically had it himself.

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds in [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}[0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}
```

Case insensitive, but you can probably define that in Java instead of the regex.

Comment: Expresso is great!  I highly second the suggestion of this program as a great way to generate and test regexes.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you posted, the following should work fine.

```
(([A-Za-z\d])*,){5}+(([\d])*,){6}+(([A-Za-z\d])*,){3}+([\d])*,[\d]*
```

In Java you should be able use it like this:

```
boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches("(([A-Za-z\\d])*,){5}+(([\\d])*,){6}+(([A-Za-z\\d])*,){3}+([\\d])*,[\\d]*");
```

I used, this tool to help in learning RegEx, it also make this really easy.
http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at some simple java regex tutorials such as [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

They'll tell you how you form regular expressions and also how to use it in java.

Answer (score 0):

This should match the pattern you request.

```
[a-z0-9]{5}[0-9]{6}[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}
```

In addition, you could add Beginning of String / End of String matches, if your string match should fail if any other chars are in it:

```
^[a-z0-9]{5}[0-9]{6}[a-z0-9]{3}[a-z]{2}$
```